# Tether testnet deployed contract addresses

Tags: testnets, faucets, usdt, tether

Does anyone know if Tether has deployed contracts on an ethereum testnet or a level 2 testnet (Mumbai / Polygon, ...) for their stablecoins (USDT, EURT, CNHT and XAUT)? If so where could I find the contract addresses and a faucet to mint some test tokens?

On their documentation I managed to find their ethereum mainnet addresses (https://tether.to/en/supported-protocols) but nothing about testnets....

Comment: In testnets it is better to deploy your own copy like other projects have done it.

Comment: indeed that was my plan B, I just wanted to see if I could connect my smart contracts to "official" Tether contracts, just like I did when using chainlink or ENS test contracts... unfortunately I guess that I will have no other choice...

Answer (score 0):

Use http://buildbear.io/ and create your own Testnet by forking Ethereum, Polygon, Binance, Optimism, Arbitrum, Fantom, and Avalanche chains, allowing you to test Tether protocol on the actual Mainnet state.